# How to reverse convert InputFormat of datetime constructor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parsing, datetime, formatting

How to reverse convert InputFormat of datetime constructor in Matlab?

`datestr` doesn't work:

```
>> startTime = datetime('2014/06/01-00:00', 'InputFormat', 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')
startTime = 
  datetime
   01-Jun-2014 00:00:00
>> datestr(startTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')
ans =
2014/00/01-00:06
```

As you see, it turns months into minutes.

How to overcome?

**UPDATE**

Format should not be hardcoded, solution should work in both ways with one given format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`'Format'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-1-Format) of your `datetime` object to the desired output and use `char()`:

```
tfmt = 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm';
startTime = datetime('2014/06/01-00:00', 'InputFormat', tfmt, 'Format', tfmt);

char(startTime)
```

Which returns:

```
>> SOcode

ans =

    '2014/06/01-00:00'
```

---

Note that this is a [documented limitation of `datestr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#btenptl-1-formatOut)

> Note
>
> The symbolic identifiers describing date and time formats are different from those that describe the display formats of datetime arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the out format (very small change) of `datestr` worked:

```
startTime = datetime('2014/06/01-00:00', 'InputFormat', 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm')
startTime = 

   01-Jun-2014 00:00:00
datestr(startTime, 'yyyy/mm/dd-HH:MM')
ans =

2014/06/01-00:00
```

Comment: I can't hardcode format, I need it reverse automatically for one given format.